# SSRS 2008 R2 URL Action Link for Outlook Message

Tags: url, reporting-services, action, ssrs-2008-r2, mailto

I have a go to action url in SSRS 2008 as expression so it opens outlook with a message:

```
="mailto:" & "emailaddress@here" & "?subject=" & "Project Name " & 
Fields!ReferenceNo.Value & "&body=" & "Hi All," + vbcrlf + 
"Please review your outstanding task/s please for " & 
Fields!ReferenceNo.Value & "." & vbcrlf & "Thank you" & vbcrlf & 
"http://sql01/reportserver?%Folder1%2fReport1&rs:Command=Render&Ref=" & 
Fields!ReferenceNo.Value
```

The email message displays ok but will not display the url link with the correct `Fields!ReferenceNo.Value` appended. It appears to stop at Report1 without appending the

[image]

If I run the link separate from the message body,manually enter a reference, or exclude the expression from starting with mailto it works. It's simply when I try to append the `Fields!ReferenceNo.Value` that it doesn't work.

Comment: Any way you can add a screenshot of the message to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping your url:

```
="mailto:" & "emailaddress@here" & "?subject=" & "Project Name " & 
Fields!ReferenceNo.Value & "&body=" & "Hi All," + vbcrlf + 
"Please review your outstanding task/s please for " & 
Fields!ReferenceNo.Value & "." & vbcrlf & "Thank you" & vbcrlf & 
System.Uri.EscapeDataString("http://sql01/reportserver?%Folder1%2fReport1&rs:Command=Render&Ref=") & 
Fields!ReferenceNo.Value
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you